# Test for old style numerals font feature (using fontspec)

Tags: xetex, conditionals, fontspec, oldstylenums

Using `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec`, I want to test if the currently selected font has old style numerals (which I use in the main font, but not in the sans font). According to the `fontspec` documentation, it should be possible to test this using `\fontspec_if_feature:nTF`. The Open Type feature for old style numerals is called `onum`. So the following code should do the job:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[]{Linux Biolinum O}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\testforonum{\fontspec_if_feature:nTF{onum}{yes}{no}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test 123. Old style: \testforonum

\textsf{Test 123. Old style: \testforonum}

\end{document}
```

However, it says "yes" in both cases. Does anybody understand why?

Comment: But both fonts do have old style nums so the test is correct. If I use e.g. Arial I get a "no". If you want to test if old style nums have been activated you will probably have to inspect the list `\l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist`.

Comment: Okay, so I apparently misunderstood the `\fontspec_if_feature:nTF` command. Thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you add an answer?

Answer (score 3):

But both fonts do have old style numbers so the test is correct. If I use e.g. Arial I get a "no". If you want to test if old style numbers have been *activated*  you will probably have to inspect the list `\l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist`